# Above point in latex

Tags: latex

I would like to know how to make a point above a symbol (ie : ẋ)
I tried `\overset{.}{x}`, but the point is very small...
Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Does `$\dot{x}$` give you what you want?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152951/181010 for a related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to write down one answer, elaborating a bit the [source cited in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152954/49683), and to add the following minimal codes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\dot{x}$

$\ddot{x}$
    
\end{document}
```

One dot (`\dot`) and two dots (`\ddot`) work in math mode as above. Three dots (`\dddot`) and four dots (`\ddddot`) the same but they require the package [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\dddot{x}$

$\ddddot{x}$

\end{document}
```

---

Instead in text mode, the package called [`stackengine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) may help:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\stackon[1pt]{x}{.}

\end{document}
```