# Newtonian notation for derivates on latex

Tags: math, latex, representation, katex, notion

I am using Notion for my studies: so I have to use Latex to represent the equations or others math stuffs. I noticed that I can use the Newtonian notation on Latex with the command `\dot` or `\ddot` (first derivative and second derivative) but I cannot represent the third with `\dddot` or with something else. Is there a way to represent that?

Comment: Not really in topic for Stack Overflow since this isn't about programming. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42443/16923 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131587/16923 discuss how `\dddot` can be re-defined so one of the packages listed there must have the original definition. Whether any of that will also work with KaTeX as indicated by your tag is a different question. You might need to contribute an implementation to KaTeX if not.

Comment: See [this answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70144333/3543233)!

Answer (score 1):

As in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70144333/3543233), three dots (`\dddot`) and four dots (`\ddddot`) in math mode require the package [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

So you have either

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\dot{x}\]

\[\ddot{x}\]
    
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\dot{x}\]

\[\ddot{x}\]

\[\dddot{x}\]

\[\ddddot{x}\]

\end{document}
```